# Linking to another page

Tags: html

Using HTML

I want to use 2 checkbox, when i click the check box 1 then it will redirect to another page, when i click the check box 2 then it will redirect to another page.

How to make a code in HTML

Need Code Help

Comment: It sounds like wildly unintuitive behavior, given how checkboxes normally work, and what the user will be expecting.

Comment: you'll need to use some client side script such as JavaScript to achieve this. This can't be done in HTML alone.

Comment: Radio buttons would be more appropriate. Can you explain the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all checkboxes are not supposed to be used for redirection purpose, however if you really want to do that, you can go about something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('checkbox1_id');
el.onclick = function(){
  document.location.href = 'somepage.html';
};

var el2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2_id');
el2.onclick = function(){
  document.location.href = 'somepage2.html';
};
```